# CakePHP: Pagination of complex query

Tags: pagination, cakephp-2.1

I have 3 tables: accounts, transactions, statements. Account hasMany transactions & statements (foreign key is account_id).

I need to retrieve the account_name, balance of billed transactions, total & count of unbilled (pending) transactions and last statement-date for all accounts with either and outstanding balance and/or unbilled transactions.

This query returns the data as expected:

```
SELECT 
    Account.id, Account.account_name, 
    Billed.balance, Pending.items, 
    Pending.amount, Stmnt.latest 
FROM 
    accounts as Account
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        account_id, 
        (SUM(`Transaction`.`debit`) - SUM(`Transaction`.`credit`)) as balance
    FROM
        `transactions` AS `Transaction`
    WHERE
        `Transaction`.`statement_id` > 0 AND
        `Transaction`.`void` = 0
    GROUP BY
        account_id
    ) AS Billed ON Billed.account_id = Account.id
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        `account_id`, 
        (SUM(`Transaction`.`debit`) - SUM(`Transaction`.`credit`)) as amount, 
        COUNT(id) AS items
    FROM
        `transactions` AS `Transaction`
    WHERE
        `Transaction`.`statement_id` = 0 AND
        `Transaction`.`void` = 0
    GROUP BY
        account_id
    ) AS Pending ON Pending.account_id = Account.id
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        `account_id`, 
        MAX(Statement.statement_date) AS latest
    FROM
        `statements` AS `Statement`
    WHERE
        `Statement`.`void` = 0
    GROUP BY
        account_id
    ) AS Stmnt ON Stmnt.account_id = Account.id
GROUP BY
    account.id
HAVING
    Billed.balance > 0 OR
    Pending.pending_ct > 0
ORDER BY
    account_name ASC
```

I'm having difficulty successfully translating this into CakePHP 2.1 find or paginate-friendly options.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hm. Although it *may* be possible to get that into a standard CakePHP query, you will probably need a lot of tricks to do so. Also CakePHP may execute some subqueries separate, which will be problematic when trying to paginate that. Personally, I would consider creating a database-view and temporarily switch the 'useTable' of my model for paginating

Comment: @thaJeztah, I hadn't thought of that approach - but I like it. I'll have to give it a go. Thanks, interesting idea!

Comment: Good luck! Also be sure to switch the useTable via `setSource()` as this will make sure that the Model will re-inspect the scheme of the table(view): http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-class-Model.html#1100-1125